# Oracle ADF Production Project integeration

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

we need to develop a web application using Oracle ADF and jdeveloper 12c.
we have 10 modules. 
Each module has developed by each member(Each member is using different system with same environment. Jdeveloper 12c). 
Finally developing all the 10 modules how we can combine all the 10 modules as a single application. 
How we can modify bindings , page flows and connection details.
By using Reusablity components?.
That means how? 
For Eg:- In Sales Modules i have Sales & Sales Return pages both are designing by two seperate members how to integerate these two as single project like Sales.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on usecase. 
But mostly u'd make each module as separate taskflow (use correct naming for classes/packages to avoid intersection). Then combine it as single shared library (or libraries if u need separate deployment) and import it into the main project.
Also same way you can reuse this taskflows in different applications.

Comment: What about Model ( ADF BC Components)? Whether i should have Model in Main Project only.

Comment: It depends. Mostly model developed as separate centralized module, so you can also deploy it as separate shared library module and use it in any other module, that may need it. However if your module is self sufficient, it may contain model for itself as well, like for example standard poll module, it may be a nice addition in your application, however not tightly integrated within it. Main downside of separete models is more db connections, more memory usage and duplication (if same db object used in different modules).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned ADF libraries are a good way to package and compose an ADF application.
One thing to note though is that you could have multiple developers working in the same project, you should use a version management system such as Git to help merge changes in such a scenario.